# Execute function only if a variable is True

Tags: python, methods, idioms

I would like to run a function only if a statement is True.
For example, i have:

```
def foo():
    # do something
```

And i want to run this only when

```
var == True
```

And in key handler I **don't** want to do something like this:

```
if k.key() == Key_UP and var:
    foo()
```

I call this function from multiple places and I don't want to repeat var condition.
Also, I **don't** want something like this:

```
def foo():
    if var:
        # do something
```

The last one I showed is the nearest to my needs, but still i think it can be done some other way. Idiomatic for Python 3.

Greetings!

PS. I want to get something like this:

```
def foo() if var == True:
    # do something
```

Comment: Maybe it's going to be more easy if you tell what you want instead of what you don't want!?

Comment: How is the syntax you want any better than the syntax you didn't like?

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid having the `# do something` code indented, you might do `if not var: return` at the top of your function.

Comment: @iCodez i think that this is enough for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Does ```var``` change often?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
 def foo():
    print('foo')

>>> bool = True
>>> if bool: foo()
foo

>>> bool = False
>>> if bool: foo()
```

If the above isn't suitable, I don't think it's clear what you'd like to do or why something like this wouldn't work:

```
def foo():
    if not var:
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where and how `var` is declared, you may be able to write a decorator, which will allow you to have a syntax like that:

```
@if_true(var)
def foo():
     # body of the function
```

However, this isn't by any means more idiomatic than a simple `if` check in the body of the function, which you (for some reason) don't want.

Comment: This won't work if you change the value of `var` after the function is defined.

Comment: True. As I said: this depends on what `var` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *short circuit* behavior of a boolean operation to accomplish the task but it is not clear that is what you are after.

```
# bit of setup
class K:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self._key = key
    def key(self):
        return self._key
def foo():
    print('\tfoo running')
    return 'foo!'
var = [True, False]
k = K(True)
m = K(False)

for thing in (k, m):
    for b in var:
        print('thing.key():{} - var:{}'.format(thing.key(), b))
        if thing.key():
            result = b and foo()
            print('\t', result)
>>> 
thing.key():True - var:True
    foo running
     foo!
thing.key():True - var:False
     False
thing.key():False - var:True
thing.key():False - var:False
>>>
```